# BottomNavigationView border top Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml

I am trying to create a border on top of the selected bottom navigation view.

Activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navigation_border"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    />
```

bottom_navigation_border.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="6dp"  android:color="@color/red_700"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This is the current output of the code. I tried adding padding but it didn't work. Is there any to make it to the top of the navigation bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for this case 9patch image would be an optimal resolution, check out how to draw such image in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)